# Substring on lua table for last 4 characters

Tags: lua

I am trying to get the last 4 characters of a field in a lua table.

My csv file looks like this:
1234, http://myurl.com

```
local list = {}
for line in io.lines("x.csv") do
    local mediaId, fURL = line:match("([^,]+),([^,]+)")
    list[#list + 1] = { mediaId = mediaId, fURL = fURL }
end

print(list[1].mediaId) -- 1234
print(list[1].fURL) -- http://myurl.com
print(list[1].fURL.tostring().sub(list[1].fURL.tostring().len() - 4)) -- expected result: last 4 character of string, eg. .com
```

What I need now are the 4 last characters. It does not matter what they are, no need for any checks just the 4 last characters. My code above causes a "attempt to call field 'tostring' (a nil value)" error.
What do I need to do to correct it?

Comment: `tostring` is a global function not a member/method function. That is `tostring(something)` not `something.tostring()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store them as a new key in the table (The function used is [`string.sub`](http://lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.sub)):

```
for line in io.lines("x.csv") do
    local mediaId, fURL = line:match("([^,]+),([^,]+)")
    list[#list + 1] = { mediaId = mediaId, fURL = fURL, last = fURL:sub(-4) }
end
```

and reference them outside of the loop as:

```
print( list[1].last )
```

Comment: thank you. i didnt even think about such a possibility

Answer (score 2):

```
local bla = string.len(tostring(list[1].fURL)) - 3
print(string.sub(tostring(list[1].fURL), bla)) -- last 4 character, yes minus 3 = last 4 character.
```